# Unable to get session cookie using axios and Express Session. But able to with Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

I have been able to find countless topics of discussion on this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me

Essentially, I have a react client that uses axios to make requests to a node js backend which uses express session

I’m able to log into the application and get a successful response. However, the response header does not include the connect.sid field. And when checking chromes devtools -> application -> cookies folder, I don’t see any cookies there for the site

I also tried testing this using IE and Firefox with the same result

Now when making the same login request via postman, I’m able to see both the connect.sid in the header and the cookie itself in the cookies tab.

In my current situation, the client and server are both running on localhost, with the client running on port 3000 and the server running on port 3001. One difference is that client is http and server is https

From my research online, these are the common things suggested, with neither working in my case

- Setting axios withCredential to “true” in react. This appears to have fixed the problem for majority of the people online. I have mine set up as well

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

- Setting the httpOnly field to false for the session cookie in the server. Below is my session configuration

```
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'BSL3562904BVAIHBP53VRFSF',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      rolling: true,
      cookie: {secure: true, httpOnly: false }
    }))
```

- Configuring the cors settings in the server. This shouldn’t affect me in this scenario as the client and server are running on the same domain, but I still covered that base anyway

```
    app.use(cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }));
```

For the origin value I tried both “localhost” and “127.0.0.1”

- Setting “trust proxy” in server

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);// trust first proxy
```

This isn’t simply an issue of not being able to retrieve cookies in the client, as I can create and attach cookies to the response and see them. It’s just the session cookie that does not appear

At this point, I’m kind of banging my head against a wall. So any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: is your react serving over https? Your express cookie says `secure: true`?

Comment: You're a life saver. My react was not serving over https. The "secure: true" configuration for the cookie is what was preventing my client from accessing the cookie @Varcorb . I feel silly for not noticing that before